# App for extracting latitude and longitude based on a location

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I am making an experimental mobile app which opens a browser in which I can detect when HTTP requests are made and extract the URL.

I would like to find the latitude / longitude of a location by targeting it on a map. However, the challenge is that the map application has to make a generic HTTP (GET) request whenever the locations changes so I can extract the latitude and longitude from the URL.

So far, I have tried these apps:

- http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html
- http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php

But I am not satisfied, because you have to click on either a link or a button to get the actual latitude and longitude which is a bit cumbersome. Also, they are not optimized for mobile devices.

Are there any other (hopefully more suitable) alternatives I should check out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using [Google Maps (Geolocation) API](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation) instead of finding an app.

Answer (score 3):

GeoLocation is an interesting field see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8180637/720176) link which lists some popular options for you. For full code to know the latitude and longitude see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8800334/720176), the link use Google API, However you can get similar results for other alternatives.

One more thing practical experiments say that Yahoo's results are more accurate sometimes. I can post full code for using Yahoo API, but first you test the Google code.. and tell your progress.. Best Wishes,